# Alternative to for loop in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to migrate stored procedure in Oracle to Sql server 2014. It has two "for loops" written in it. I thought of using cursors but I would appreciate if someone has better alternative to cursors or it is appropriate to use it ?
The procedure takes each deleted programs from a table present in db_1 schema and deletes the associated values from the table present in second DB_2

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PD_DELETE
AS
v_PID   VARCHAR2(40 BYTE);
BEGIN

  -- Finding all the deleted subparts in  DB_1
  FOR i IN
  (SELECT ad.ID            AS ID
  , ad.D_FAM          AS D_FAM
  , SUBSTR( ad.ID, 0, 18 ) AS A_fac_id
  , SUBSTR (ad.ID, 20, 7) AS A_CODE
  , SUBSTR( ad.ID, 20 )    AS A_SubCode
   FROM DB_1.IC_DELETE ad
   WHERE ad.IC_Status_ID <> 'P'
   AND ad.D_FAM = 'A_Program_Subpart'
   )

LOOP

Database DB_2

SELECT A_ID INTO v_PID  FROM DB_2.IC_Program
WHERE A_ID = i.a_fac_id
and A_CODE = i.A_CODE;

DELETE
FROM DB_2.AP_SUBPART t
WHERE t.A_ID = v_PID
AND t.SUBPARTCODE = i.A_SubCode;


--- Reset the status in  DB_1
UPDATE DB_1.IC_DELETE ad
SET ad.IC_Status_ID = 'P',
ad.IC_DATE = SYSDATE
WHERE ad.ID = i.ID
AND ad.D_FAM = i.D_FAM;

-- Commit data for a single record
  COMMIT;

END LOOP;

    ========================================  
    SQL SERVER using cursor
    AS
    BEGIN
    Declare @V_ID varchar(40),
    @id varchar(10), @fam varchar(max), @code varchar(max)

    Declare DB_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FOR 
    Select id, fam, code from IC
       where ind <> 'P'
    OPEN DB_Cursor
    BEGIN 
    FETCH DB_Cursor into @id, @fam, @code
    select @V_id = id from AP
    ...............
      DELETE 
      FROM 
      ..............

      UPDATE 
      .............
      END 
      Close DB_Cursor
      Deallocate DB_Cursor
```

Comment: You have minimized the code so much that you removed all the important details. From what I see left though there is no need for any kind of looping at all in Oracle or any DBMS. You should be able to do this with a single delete statement followed by a single update statement.

Comment: What on Earth manner of indentation is this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good grief your column and table names are so cryptic!!!

It is a shot in the dark here are it is not 100% clear what you are trying to do but I think this should be pretty much it.

This would replace all the looping here.

```
update ad
SET ind = 'P'
    , date = GETDATE()
from ad
join IC on IC.id = a.ID
where IC.ind <> 'P'

delete IC
from IC
join AP on AP.afid = IC.afacid
    AND AP.acode = IC.code
```

Comment: Thanks Sean, my bad I updated the store procedure with more information. It is actually taking each deleted items from one DB and deleting the associated values from second DB.

Comment: That won't change the basic idea. You just need to add the database name and schema in the queries posted. It seems you have changed some of the names of things and some of the join criteria a bit since I posted but whatever. You should be able to sort that little bit out.